# User is showing up twice in Communities

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, moderators

I was looking at the WorldBuilding.SE Sandbox, and I noticed it was owned by a *real user*, unlike the PPCG sandbox. I clicked on the user's name, and this is what I saw: [image: None]

Clicking on "Main user",

[image: N one]

Why is this user listed as an OpenSource.SE mod *twice*?

As requested, the user is [ArtOfCode](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2685/artofcode).

Comment: Can you link the user?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I did not for privacy reasons. Should I have?

Comment: Looks like a failed account merge, which is probably pretty rare for moderators.

Comment: Why go through another election when you can just clone a mod?

Comment: Yeah. Let's clone Oded too @jamal

Comment: Heh. And there was me thinking nobody had noticed my surreptitious duplication. TL;DR: I accidentally made @AdamLear work in the evening :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We had a bug with a mod-only feature where it accidentally created duplicate profiles when used by mods who moderate multiple sites. There was no harm done here beyond it looking weird.

The profiles have been merged, so ArtOfCode no longer has evil twins...that we know of.

Comment: Actually, that might've been the good twin...